# NameError in UsersController#index uninitialized constant User::FILL_IN

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Rails and currently following Michael Hartl's [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book). When I try adding these last lines in **app/models/user.rb** at the end of Chapter 2: A toy app, I run into this error:

*(Error)*

> NameError in UsersController#index
>   uninitialized constant User::FILL_IN

*(Code)*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :microposts
  validates FILL_IN, presence: true
  validates FILL_IN, presence: true
end
```

Sorry if this might be a stupid error of typo, or syntax but can someone please help me understand what I've done wrong?

Thanks

Comment: It says *"Update Listing 2.19 by replacing FILL_IN with the appropriate code to validate the presence of name and email attributes in the User model (Figure 2.20)."*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FILL_IN` is a placeholder.

Replace `FILL_IN` with the name of the column you want validated. Example below:

```
validates :title, presence: true
validates :description, presence: true
```

The above code, inside a model, will ensure that both the `title` and `description` columns (fields) are filled and not `nil` before saving the new record, ( or an updated record ).

> PS: this is example, assuming the presence of `title` and `description` fields in the model. these would have to be replaced with the name of the columns of interest which you want validated for presence (which will be `name` and `email` in this case).

Hope this is explanatory enough and is helpful.

**Update:**

Look at the [exercise here](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/toy_app#sec-toy_app_exercises). This point is made more obvious. :)

Comment: Thanks for the fast response you made. Just one question: why did we have to use the code `validate FILL_IN, presence: true` in the tutorial if it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, as I said, it is a placeholder. This is a tutorial, and there will be exercises to help you understand better instead of just copying code and seeing it work.

Answer (score 0):

Correct solution:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :microposts
    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :email, presence: true
end
```